# why does NOT UIWebView load the content in the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UITableView` within a `UINavigationController`,when I select a cell in the table view,it should slide to a `UIWebView`

```
    //code in table view delegate(tableviewcontroller)
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.baidu.com/"];
        self.webViewController.title = @"UIWebViewTest";
        self.webViewController.URL = url;
        [self.navigationController
            pushViewController:self.webViewController animated:YES];
   }
```

`self.webViewController` was initialized by

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //..
        //other code
        //..
        YGGWebViewController *wvc = [self.storyboard
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wvc"];  
        self.webViewController = wvc;
    }
```

in the `YGGWebViewController`, I have a `NSURL *URL` property and override the setter

```
    - (void)setURL:(NSURL *)URL{
        _URL = URL;
        if (_URL) {
            NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_URL];
            [self.webView  loadRequest:req];
        }
    }
```

besides,`YGGWebViewController` also have a `UIWebView *webView` property linked to a `UIWebView` in storyboard.

what odd is the web view does not display anything when it slides to the screen in the first time,but it will show the website in the second time（go back to the table view by navigation bar,and select a cell again）.

**Environment**
xcode-7.0
deployment target-7.0
OS X Yosemite-10.10.5

P.S
if I move the code

```
   if (_URL) {
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_URL];
        [self.webView  loadRequest:req];

    }
```

to `viewDidLoad` in `YGGWebViewController`,it works right.but why?

Comment: How long did you wait? Add some logging and the web view delegate methods.

Comment: @Wain about 2~3 minutes.actually,no matter how much time I have waited during the first time, once I went back and went into it again,the web view will display the website correctly

Comment: @Wain I have test web view delegate methods,nothing print in webViewDidStartLoad and webViewFinishLoad at the first time.

Comment: @Rekha  yes,it works at the second time.but not a error.

Comment: @ygg i didn't get any error. for the first time only it worked

Comment: debug to check that you accessor is called, that the outlet is set, ...

Comment: @Rekha thank you for your testing,but it still does not work in my code.

Comment: @Wain I have checked again,I didn't find any problem.

Comment: Based on your update you didn't check the outlet, so it looks like the issue is that the view doesn't exist the first time when you set the URL so you call nil

Comment: @Wain you are RIGHT! it is nil!why?I have initialized the webviewcontroller in viewDidLoad,  why didn't webView be initialized simultaneously?